# Nest.js: Custom decorator that will return parameter from request

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, reflect-metadata

In a custom decorator Param I have a console.log that is run once. How to make it to return me a fresh value of id on each request like in nestjs?

```
@Get('/:id')
async findUser (
    @Param() id: string | undefined // is not called each time when acces method findUser
  ): Promise<User> {
}



export const Param = () => (target: any, key: string, index: number)  => {
    var indices = Reflect.getMetadata('request', target, key);
    console.log('test', indices)
}



Reflect.defineMetadata('request', event, currentController.prototype, route.methodName);
```

Comment: `Param` can't really do anything afaict. It's the `Get` decorator that needs to access the metadata on the parameters, and use it when the decorated method is calling the implementation.

Comment: @Bergi I have a custom Controller and Get decorator, and using it's metadata I create a router and page are opened. But all decorators are called once that is ok for that decorators, but for Para decorator isn't

Comment: @Bergi or in nestjs data in param come from dependency injection like iversify?

Comment: Param decorator only say which is need to be injected `const metadata = Reflect.defineMetadata(ROUTE_ARGS_METADATA, ... )` and after that `this.reflectParamInjectables(cls, token, ROUTE_ARGS_METADATA);` inject data.